Keycloak registration with code verification (through email)
I’m fairly new to Keycloak and have got a use case where we need to change / modify the Keycloak user registration flow to include a step that does code verification sent through email.
Here’s the expected flow -

Initially, when the form loads, the except email field, all other fields of registration form should be disabled or hidden.
There needs to be setup (a mini form) with a label, input text to enter code and two buttons - Send Verification Code and Verify Code, which will send code to email and verify the code, probably I guess the form actions.
Once verified the code, user should see remaining fields of registration - firstname, lastname, password etc. to fill in and continue registration.
Since email is verified, the registration process would mark user email as verified in the flow and may not require action - Verify Email.
So the goal is to get this mini code verification form integrated into register.ftl and the flow. My guess this will require custom SPIs to be developed.

I have been reading implementing FormActions, FormAuthenticator however, kinda got lost or able to connect, so any help or advice or direction would be appreciated.
Thanks!
